# DataContractResolver is not called

Tags: c#, wcf, datacontractserializer

I’m debugging a WCF issue where our custom `DataContractResolver` is not called. We are self-hosting the wcf-service, and creating a `ServiceHost` like this:

```
    private static ServiceHost GetServiceHost(DataContractResolver dataContractResolver, Binding binding, string address)
    {
        var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(ServiceImpl));
        var endpoint = serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint((typeof(IServiceInterface)), binding, address);
        foreach (var operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>().DataContractResolver = dataContractResolver;

        return serviceHost;
    }
```

I have attached a debugger and checked that the behaviour is indeed set correctly. We create a client like this:

```
    private static IServiceInterface GetChannel(DataContractResolver dataContractResolver, Binding binding, EndpointAddress endpointAddress)
    {
        var channelFactory = new DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceInterface>(new CallbackObject(), binding, endpointAddress);
        foreach (var operation in channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations)
            operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>().DataContractResolver = dataContractResolver;

        return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
    }
```

Here the behaviour is attached correctly as well. However, when I make a call from the channel created, my `dataContractResolver` is not called (checked with breakpoints, `Console.WriteLine` and even throwing exceptions). I have compared my approach with MSDN documentation and several blog articles, but can't see why it does not work. What am I missing?

I've created an minimal example solution which can be downloaded from the gist [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9342358). *The gist only contains the files. In my solution they are divided into three different projects, Server (Console app), Client (Console app) and Common (Class lib), as indicated by their namespaces*

**EDIT:**
I noticed that the resolver is called for any `DataMember` properties that have type `object`. It still doesn't run for the entire contract type, though,

Comment: I have recreated the problem in a minimal solution, which I could post if required, but at least discussions on Meta indicate that this is bad practice?

Comment: Possibly load it up on github as a gist?

Comment: @StuartLC: Good idea, thanks. Will edit the gist into the question